How to close in part of attic space
I have a walk-in on my second story home with an attic space extending into essentially the third story. Others in my community are built similar and some have this second story space finished to be temperature controlled storage space and I would like to do the same.
My worry is that the space being closed would cause humidity issues as I am in the southeast US and things get a bit humid. Not too many snowy days but we get a week or so each year of snow that quickly melts off after a couple days.
I would ideally install soffit insulation baffles along each open soffit and extend it for a certain length up and install insulation rolls up from there. The 45 degree ceiling terminates at the start of the third story and would be impossible to simply use the baffles up further to continue the airflow beyond this second story area. I’ve got plenty of photos but unsure how to attach here as no photos are allowed in be post it seems.
This would fully cut off half of the attic from the other 3rd story section and limit airflow. Is this feasible project or does this seem ill-advised? Thanks!
Photos


I spent some time reading and looking at your photos and I'm still not sure I understand. This looks like a ceiling insulation project to me. What's all the talk about extending walls? (I'd start by fixing the existing insulation. I see wall batts that don't reach the top wall plate, and I see baffles with nothing contacting them.)

Agree with @isherwood.  It's not clear what you intend to do.  But whatever you do, it appears you have some beams across the roof where you need to maintain some airflow between the roof sheeting and whatever you fasten to the bottom of the rafters.  You need to maintain a clear path for air between the eaves and the ridge vent (please confirm you have one).
